# Maintain scroll position after adding items to array in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Have list of messages displayed via ng-repeat, when user scrolls to top older messages are loaded via ion refresher.  Desired behavior is for older messages to be added above the current messages, and the scroll position of current messages to be maintained.

HTML

```
<ion-content id="messageScroller" delegate-handle="userMessageScroll">

  <ion-refresher pulling-icon="ion-ios-arrow-thin-down" refreshing-text="loading messages" on-refresh="moreMessages()">
  </ion-refresher>

  <div ng-repeat="message in convo.messages">
    {{message.text}}
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

JS

```
$scope.moreMessages = function() {
  $scope.convo.messages = olderMessages().concat($scope.convo.messages)
}
```

Problem is when more messages is called, the ion-content scrolls to the top (stays at the top?).

How to set scroll position so loading older messages just makes the older messages accessable by scrolling up?  Like it does in iMessage, or other chat apps?

Answer (score 2):

look into [$ionicScrollDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/). You can set and get the scroll position

Comment: This is not ideal, as $ionicScrollDelegate gets you the scroll position relative to the top of the scroll container.  This position will always be zero in the situation described above.  You might be able to do something with anchors, but have not had luck with this either.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing in my app and made a directive, just place the `<load-more-at-top>` directive before an `<ion-list>` within an `<ion-content>`

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2zN5YtO4Ncpqactym8n?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('loadMoreAtTop', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { onScroll: '&onScroll' },
    require: '^$ionicScroll',
    template: function() {
        return '<ion-refresher pulling-text="More..." on-refresh="growBounds()"></ion-refresher>';
    },
    link: function($scope, $element, attrs, scrollCtrl) {
      var scroller = scrollCtrl.$element[0];
      var lastHeight, 
          loading = false;
      $scope.growBounds = function growBounds() {
          loading = true;
          lastHeight = scroller.scrollHeight;
          console.log('lastHeight', lastHeight);
          $scope.onScroll();
      }

      function resetScrollPosition() {
          var height = scroller.scrollHeight;
          var difference = height - lastHeight;
          console.log('difference', difference, 'height', height, 'lastHeight', lastHeight);
          // reset the scroll based on previous height
          scrollCtrl.scrollTo(scrollCtrl.getScrollPosition().left, difference, true);
      }

      function finishGrowBounds() {
        if(loading) {
          $timeout(function() {
              loading = false;
              resetScrollPosition();
              $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
          }, 0);
        }
      }

      $scope.$parent.$on('scroll.loaded', finishGrowBounds)
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This solution is working great on iOS. However I get this error in console when using this in Android platform:

`Refresher must be immediate child of ion-content or ion-scroll`

Is there any way arround this?